# Filter child node query on AngularFire2 firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have this data structure in my firebase.

```
  "produtos" : {
    "3" : {
      "data" : "2017-09-21",
      "fornecedor" : {
        "cnpj" : "123234534534",
        "fantasia" : "Barreirinha"
      },
      "nNF" : 3,
      "peso" : 3,
      "precoCompra" : 6,
      "vendido" : false
    },
    "123" : {
      "data" : "2017-09-14",
      "fornecedor" : {
        "cnpj" : "123234534534",
        "fantasia" : "Barreirinha"
      },
      "nNF" : 123,
      "peso" : 23000,
      "precoCompra" : 2.21,
      "vendido" : false
    }
  }
```

I need to get a list of values of objects that contain the `CNPJ` key.

I'm using Angular, AngularFire2 and TypeScript, but I can not understand.

```
retrieveProdutos(cnpjFornecedor: string) {
    this.produtos = this.db.list(this.paths.pathProduto, {
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'cnpj',
        equalTo: cnpjFornecedor,
        orderByKey: true,
      }
    });
  }
```

How do I get this list? is returning empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can only query one field ;

```
query: {
  orderByChild: "vendido",
  equalTo: "false" 
}
```

which for example would give you all the child nodes that have their `vendido` child key set to `false`.

Also, if you want to access each child value, you could do:

```
this.produtos.subscribe(produtos => {

    produtos.forEach(produto => {

        console.log("produto:", produto);

        // And here you can access each produto data 

    });
});
```

or, depending on you access your database:

```
 yourRef.on("value", (snapshot) => {

       snapshot.forEach((child) => {

                var produto = child.val();

                console.log("produto nNF", produto.nNF);

        });

});
```

Comment: but I need to filter by 'cnpj'. I tried "orderByChild: 'fornecedor/cnpj'" but I could not

Comment: Does cnpj has a value or is it one of your parent node? If it's a parent node and you just want to filter the results using cnpj, then you could just add this to your query:   query: { orderByChild: "cnpj'" }

Comment: orderByKey, instead, would sort the results of your query by their ascending key values.

Comment: it has a value. I have to filter the list this way: CNPJ = 123

Comment: Great, then  query: { orderByChild: 'CNPJ', equalTo: 123 } would work just fine!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155053/discussion-between-alex-and-rafael-silva).

Answer (score 0):

Given your JSON, you're filtering by a nested property at a known path. This is possible by specifying the path to the property in the query:

```
retrieveProdutos(cnpjFornecedor: string) {
    this.produtos = this.db.list(this.paths.pathProduto, {
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'fornecedor/cnpj',
        equalTo: cnpjFornecedor
      }
    });
  }
```

Update: on second read you say you want to return items that have a value for `nNF`. In this case you can filter with:

```
retrieveProdutos(cnpjFornecedor: string) {
    this.produtos = this.db.list(this.paths.pathProduto, {
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'nNF',
        startAt: 0
      }
    });
  }
```

You'll want to note that Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property. For an example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Comment: Excuse me. My query only filters a field. I do not need to filter nNF, I just typed it wrong. The correct is to filter only the CNPJ

Comment: I tried orderByChild: 'fornecedor/cnpj', But I did not succeed. Returns an empty list.

Comment: Hmmm... that should work, although there's some unknowns in your code. Can you replace `cnpjFornecedor ` with a hardcoded value `"123234534534"`?